# Cruise Control .net Changing Log File appereance

Tags: powershell, cruisecontrol.net, dashboard

i would like to change the apperance of the log file, generated by ccnet. It is useful, if the error messages are separated from the original Log Messages, but in order to debug, it is a bit tricky to see, when the error really happened. Our powershell skript runs for 6-8 hours and creates about 38k lines in the log file, so i would really apprechiate a solution, how i could list the errors with the other lines in the log files. Additionally it would be cool, if all the errors would still appear separatedly.
So far i have not found a lot documentary that explained how to change the log file output...

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is logged, but in the end, logs produced during the build are put into the build-log file, that you will find in *artifacts* folder.

Then this logs are transposed into html output using xsl transforms. If none of the built-in reports is useful to you, you can create a custom xsl and plug it in, see the *dashboard.config* file, the following section allows for adding additional xsl transforms:

```
<buildReportBuildPlugin>        
      <xslReportBuildPlugin description="MSBuild Log" actionName="MSBuildBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\MSBuild4Log.xsl"/>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the error messages are going to be you can parse them with an xsl file and generate some html that will show up in the build emails. The following goes in ccservice.exe.config.

```
    <xslFiles>
        <file name="c:\path\to\custom_errors.xsl"/>
    </xslFiles>
```

custom_errors.xsl is an xsl file that finds the error messages in the raw build log xml and then generates html from them. This html will show up in the build emails. You have to create custom_errors.xsl. It's a significant amount of work to get working the first time especially if you're new to xml/xsl/html/css. If you undertake this I suggest doing all the testing outside of ccnet using a xsl transformer and inputting a sample ccnet build log. ccnet uses a css file to style the html so be aware of that. You can edit this too.

Note you have to restart the ccnet service after editing ccservice.exe.config.